# TypeError: soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror, lxml

When I use this code

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
```

I got this type of error

```py
super(BeautifulSoup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'features'
```

But when I use only

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
```

Its work well but didn't show in html.

How to fix it...?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you pass the string `'lxml'` as a second argument to a method that isn't expecting a second argument? The question is unclear.

Comment: when i use this code its show error BeautifulStoneSoup(page.text, 'lxml') to this  TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'features'  or which code should i use to convert the page as html..?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulStoneSoup` is not the same thing as `BeautifulSoup`, and is probably not the one you want.  `BeautifulStoneSoup` is specifically designed for XML and thus does not accept a parser.  `BeautifulSoup` can handle several different formats, including HTML.

I suggest you replace `BeautifulStoneSoup` with`BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#xml)

> There is no longer a `BeautifulStoneSoup` class for parsing XML. To parse XML you pass in “xml” as the second argument to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'xml')
```

And about the `TypeError`, @John Coleman has given you the reason in the comments.